# Output a result after analyzing an uploaded file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm trying to solve a problem at hand, I don't really know PHP nor Wordpress, just what I've got in a couple of hours. I know a little of webapp2 with Python, so the Wordpress event driven style is confusing me.

**The objective**

There is a Wordpress page where there is a form to upload a file. I want to analyze such file and then modify (or redirect) my user's page and show him some nice analysis results.

**What I know so far**

I know I can modify the `functions.php` file of a theme and add something like this to catch the post request:

```
function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    /**
     * Take the uploaded file and send it through a POST to my webservice
     * Then use the response to modify the wordpress page where the user was
     * or
     * redirect him to a results page
     */

     //https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post
     $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array('body' => $parameters));

     if (is_wp_error( $response )) {
         // $response->get_error_message()
     } else {
         // $response['body']
     }
}
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_contact_form', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
add_action( 'admin_post_contact_form', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
```

Also, the html form would be something like this:

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And that's pretty much what I got, I would appreciate any help with the  `prefix_admin_add_foobar` function so it can display the results to my user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link for solving your problem

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to follow following steps..

1. Upload file from your form, In WordPress
2. You can upload file using this code.
3. require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php' );
       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php' );
       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/media.php' );
       require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php');

   ```
   $post_ids = get_the_ID();
   $attach_id = media_handle_upload('attachemes', $post_ids);
   $avatarPaths = wp_get_attachment_url($attach_id);
   $img = $avatarPaths;
   ```
4. Once file upload successfully `<?php wp_redirect( home_url()."/client" ); exit; ?>`
5. 5 get post client page.

I hope its helpful for you